# DHCP Server：multi subnet not working

Tags: linux, centos, isc-dhcpd

I want to let DHCP server offer different subnet address to different group of mac address.

I have been successful to offer multi subnet addresses to DHCP clients.

I have used the "class" as filter of mac address, but it is not working.

Below is my dhcpd.conf

```
class "class1" {
   match if
   (substring(hardware,1,6) = 04:7d:7b:f1:69:b2) or
   (substring(hardware,1,6) = 04:7d:7b:d8:bb:60);
}

subnet 172.16.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
     deny members of "class1";
     deny unknown-clients;
     range 172.16.51.100 172.16.51.200;
  }
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 172.16.51.254;
  option broadcast-address 172.16.51.255;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}

subnet 172.16.52.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
    allow members of "class1";
    deny unknown-clients;
    range 172.16.52.100 172.16.52.200;
  }
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 172.16.52.254;
  option broadcast-address 172.16.52.255;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}


subnet 172.16.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
    range 172.16.50.100 172.16.50.200;
    deny known-clients;
    allow unknown-clients;
  }
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 172.16.50.254;
  option broadcast-address 172.16.50.255;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
  if exists user-class and option user-class = "iPXE" {
    filename "bootstrap.ipxe";
  } else {
    filename "undionly.kpxe";
  }
  next-server   172.16.50.31;
}
```

Now, I have a new machine named "M", which mac is 54:ab:3a:3d:2c:7a. I don't want to let it get the ip in 172.16.51.0/24 & 172.16.52.0/24, but in 172.16.50.0/24. However, it didn't work.

I am sure that I have deleted the records of both of DHCP server and DHCP client.

What should I do?

Comment: Did the machine got IP before you created the filter or deleted the leases file? Active leases have priority over other methods of giving IP addresses.

Comment: I used tcpdump to make sure there is no dhcp packet between server and client after I deleted the records, and before client sent the discover  packet. I deleted both of server's leases file and client's leases file.

Comment: Have you deleted `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`?

Comment: Yes, I deleted `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` after stopping the `dhcpd.service`

Comment: can you share the steps if you have fixed this problem ?

Comment: @KMG It is a bad news. I did not solve this problem. In the end, I deprecated the DHCP package and build a fake DHCP server that matched my needs in Python. After the client getting the wrong IP, the fake DHCP server would login the client and set the correct IP in static mode.